# Google OAuth Consent Screen Display Issues

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-apps, google-developers-console, google-identity

I am currently trying to verify my Google OAuth App, and for the demo video I need to show the App Name and Client ID on the OAuth Client. However, I am only able to get the `domain.com` to show up. I have configured my App Name in Google Cloud Console. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue and verified my app! Turns out, you only need to show your App name and client id in some way in the Demo video and configure it in Google Cloud Console.

Comment: okay let me try for it. I wish i could passed this verification too...